# Why do I get get errors for my "public static void main( String[] args) {"?

Tags: class, web-applications, syntax-error, program-entry-point

My end goal here is to bring this to an App UI. Trying to create a Property Score Checklist by having a series of question having to input a score from 0 to 3.0 and a weighted score along side it.

Besides the 1st one the rest of my "public static void main( String[] args) {" bring me  a "Error:(41, 13) java: illegal start of expression"

Any ideas why? its the only thing keeping it from running and compiling

```
package sample;

public class exterior {
    private String description;
    private double weight;
    private double score;

    public exterior (String description,double weight, double score) {
        this.description = description;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.score = score;

    }
    public double getFinalScore() {
       return score * weight;

    }
public static void main( String[] args) {
    exterior e1 = new exterior ("Free from debris/rubbish/grafiti score low for high amount of debris",0.15d,2.0d );
    exterior e2 = new exterior ("Clearly identifiable as the property in mind",0.09d,1.0d );
    exterior e3 = new exterior ("Level of street noise (score low for high noise)", 0.12d, 1.2d);
    exterior e4 = new exterior ("Proximity: Distance to nearest public transportation and grocery store", 0.21d, 2.4d);
    exterior e5 = new exterior ("Overall safe and welcoming exterior area feel", 0.24d, 1.0d);



     class entry {
        private String description;
        private double weight;
        private double score;

        public entry (String description,double weight, double score) {
            this.description = description;
            this.weight = weight;
            this.score = score;

        }
        public double getFinalScore() {
            return score * weight;

            public static void main( String[] args) {
    entry en1 = new entry ("Free from debris/rubbish/or other items such as suitcases and laundry (score low for high amount of debris)",0.15d, 3.0d);
    entry en2 = new entry ("Reception exists, if no reception a viable alternative entry area in a building or approaching a unit", 0.09d, 2.5d);
    entry en3 = new entry ("Lighting sufficient ",0.09d, 1.2d);
    entry en4 = new entry ("Free from odor", 0.15d, 0.24d);
    entry en5 = new entry ("Overall welcoming feel", 0.24d, 2.6d);

     class inside {
        private String description;
        private double weight;
        private double score;

        public inside (String description, double weight, double score) {
            this.description = description;
            this.weight = weight;
            this.score = score;

        }
        public double getFinalScore() {
            return score * weight;

            public static void main ( String[] args) {
    inside i1 = new inside ("Hallways/lifts/stairways free from debris/rubbish (score low for high amount of debris)", 0.15d, 2.3d);
    inside i2 = new inside ("Emergency exits clearly signposted", 0.15d, 0.5d);
    inside i3 = new inside ("The doors/walls/ceilings clean and free of damage and marks", 0.12d, 1.9d);
    inside i4 = new inside ("The carpet/flooring clean and free of damage and marks", 0.18d, 3.0d);
    inside i5 = new inside ("Lift present and in working order", 0.09d, 2.7d);
    inside i6 = new inside ("Are all keys, mailbox, FOBS, codes, and lock boxes present and working",0.09d, 1.9d);
    inside i7 = new inside ("Lighting sufficient throughout", 0.09d, 2.0d);
    inside i8 = new inside ("Free from odor",0.15d, 2.4d);
    inside i9 = new inside ("Noise level (score low for high noise)", 0.21d, 3.0d);
    inside i10 = new inside ("Overall hospitality feel", 0.24d, 3.0d);

     class Condition {
        private String description;
        private double weight;
        private double score;

        public Condition (String description, double weight, double score ) {
            this.description = description;
            this.weight = weight;
            this.score = score;

        }
        public double getFinalScore() {
            return score * weight;

            public static void main ( String[] args) {
    Condition c1 = new Condition ("Door key/fob in working order", 0.09d, 2.4d);
    Condition c2 = new Condition ("Free from debris/rubbish", 0.18d, 1.3d);
    Condition c3 = new Condition ("The doors/walls/ceilings clean and free of damage and marks", 0.12d, 2.1d);
    Condition c4 = new Condition ("The carpet/flooring clean and free of damage and marks", 0.18d, 2.9d);
    Condition c5 = new Condition ("Lighting",0.09d, 2.6d);
    Condition c6 = new Condition ("Odor", 0.15d, 1.7d);
    Condition c7 = new Condition ("All lights/windows/drawers/doors/blinds/curtains in working order and free from damage", 0.09d, 2.3d);
    Condition c8 = new Condition ("Furtiture free from wear/stains/odor/damage", 0.15d, 2.1d );
    Condition c9 = new Condition ("Surfaces clean: Countertops/desks/dressers/tables", 0.09d, 2.1d);
    Condition c10 = new Condition ("Porcelain clean and working: Toilet/shower/sinks ", 0.15d, 2.4d);
    Condition c11 = new Condition ("Appliances clean and working: Fridge/oven/hob/dishwaser/washer/coffee maker/microwave/kettle", 0.15d, 2.6d);
    Condition c12 = new Condition ("Windows/patio/blinds/curatins/doors all clean and in working order", 0.15d, 3.0d);
    Condition c13 = new Condition ("Pictures/mirrors hung correctly and free from damage", 0.06d, 3.0d);

     class Basics {
        private String description;
        private double weight;
        private double score;

        public Basics (String description, double weight, double score) {
            this.description = description;
            this.weight = weight;
            this.score = score;

        }
        public double getFinalScore() {
            return score * weight;

            public static void main ( String[] args) {
    Basics b1 = new Basics ("Welcome basket and fully stocked", 0.09d, 2.6d);
    Basics b2 = new Basics ("Welcome binder and/or explanation of apartment electricals", 0.09d, 3.0d);
    Basics b3 = new Basics ("Sufficient and matching cutlery/glasses/utensils", 0.09d, 2.4d);
    Basics b4 = new Basics ("Adequate seating - studio / 1 bed (2), 2 bed (4), 3 bed (6)", 0.06d, 2.5d);
    Basics b5 = new Basics ("Fully equipped kitchen including hob and oven ", 0.09d, 1.9d);
    Basics b6 = new Basics ("Overall homey feel",0.03d, 3.0d);

     class Health {
        private String description;
        private double weight;
        private double score;

        public Health (String description, double weight, double score) {
            this.description = description;
            this.weight = weight;
            this.score = score;

        }
        public double getFinalScore() {
            return score * weight;

            public static void main ( String[] args) {
    Health h1 = new Health ("Safe present", 0.06d, 3.0d);
    Health h2 = new Health ("Multiple locks - deadlock / chain ", 0.09d, 2.3d);
    Health h3 = new Health ("Electical outlets operational and appear professional maintained", 0.09, 3.0d);
    Health h4 = new Health ("Fire alarms", 0.12d, 2.5d);
    Health h5 = new Health ("Fire blankets/extinguisher", 0.12d, 3.0d);
    Health h6 = new Health ("Evacuation plan clearly marked", 0.12d, 3.0d);
    Health h7 = new Health ("Windows and doors appropriate for health and safety emergencies", 0.12d, 2.6d);

    System.out.println("Total score for all fields : ");
    System.out.println( e1.getFinalScore() + e2.getFinalScore() + e3.getFinalScore() + e4.getFinalScore() + e5.getFinalScore() + en1.getFinalScore() );
    System.out.println(en1.getFinalScore() + en2.getFinalScore() + en3.getFinalScore() + en4.getFinalScore() + en5.getFinalScore() );
    System.out.println(i1.getFinalScore() + i2.getFinalScore() + i3.getFinalScore() + i4.getFinalScore() + i5.getFinalScore() + i6.getFinalScore() + i7.getFinalScore() + i8.getFinalScore() + i9.getFinalScore() + i10.getFinalScore());
    System.out.println(c1.getFinalScore() + c2.getFinalScore() + c4.getFinalScore() + c5.getFinalScore() + c6.getFinalScore() + c7.getFinalScore() + c8.getFinalScore() + c9.getFinalScore() + c10.getFinalScore() + c11.getFinalScore() + c12.getFinalScore() + c13.getFinalScore());
    System.out.println(b1.getFinalScore() + b2.getFinalScore() + b3.getFinalScore() + b4.getFinalScore() + b5.getFinalScore() + b6.getFinalScore());
    System.out.println(h1.getFinalScore() + h2.getFinalScore() + h3.getFinalScore() + h4.getFinalScore() + h5.getFinalScore() + h6.getFinalScore() + h7.getFinalScore());


            }

        }
    }
            }
        }
    }
            }

        }
    }
    }

            }
        }
    }
    }

            }

}
}
```

Comment: Not directly your problem, but you can only have one main. Once your fix this error, that'll come up. Also, what is going on at the end there with the brackets!? You might want to sort that out before it becomes too confusing to fix.

Comment: The problem though is `getFinalScore` is missing a closing brace, or you have main inside of `getFinalScore`.

Comment: Ah yes, all the closing brackets pilled up at the end so ill pare them up accordingly. So am creating a new class after each "public static void main ( String[] args) {"? . If so ill be looking to create 5 classes

Comment: You can only have one main in the entire program.